# Make photoshop 32bit open by default. (instead of 64bit)

Tags: 64-bit, adobe-photoshop, 32-bit, file-association

How can I make the 32bit version of photoshop open by default?

As it is now, if I open anything that is a photoshop document, the 64bit version opens instead.  I have a bunch of 32bit filters and plug ins which do not work in the 64bit version.  It takes up a lot of time to close, then reopen 32bit.

Comment: What is the OS you're running? CS3? CS4?

Comment: Take a quick look: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/373427

Comment: Windows 7 64bit Ultimate.  CS4.

Comment: reinstall it,it ask for an option to default 32 bit or 64 bit!
by the way,64 bit works better than 32bit!

Answer (score 1):

For the double-click opening, adjust your Explorer file associations under Tools --> Folder Options --> File Types. Pick out the PSD file type and then choose "Change" to assign a new file handler.

Photoshop 32-bit is located at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe PhotoshopCS4\Photoshop.exe